Unselecting a radio button using another button called "Reset" in java
I am unable to deselect a radio button.This is part of the code:
public void clearFields(){
 //to clear the text from the textfield
    tf1.setText("");
    tf2.setText("");
    tf5.setText("");
    tf6.setText("");
    tf7.setText("");
    p1.setText("");
    p2.setText("");
//to deselect the radio button
    radio1.setSelected(false);
    radio2.setSelected(false);
//to deselect the checkboxes
    option1.setState(false);
    option2.setState(false);
    option3.setState(false);

}

